# Xcode shows wrong behaviour fir signing certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing-certificate, xcode8.2

Hy,
I am using Xcode 8.2.1. Bundle identifier belongs to distribution. I correctly chose the Team. I have downloaded all provisioning profile from `Xcode > Preferences > Apple IDs > Team` etc etc.

Why Xcode always show 'iPhone developer' instead of 'iPhone distribution'? Please see both images below.

More info: My system `Keychain Access` exactly have 4 certificates. Two of them, are for developer and distribution, other two are for push - development and distribution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please connect you mobile and select iPhone for the testing and clean your project.

Comment: Disable automatically manage signing and set certificate manually.

Comment: @ChandreshKachariya: yes this is another solution to deal with this problem, to do it manually the way back we used to do it, but how to do with automatically.

Comment: open xCode->Preferences->Account delete it and once again add your apple id after create new certificate.
Before add apple id clear your trace folder.

Comment: @KetanShinde I think you have multiple Profiles installed in the system. Goto  `XCode->Preferences->Accounts` select your account and click on `View Details` on the panel in the right side, from there delete all related profiles, after you delete goto to your developer account and download latest, click once to install, make sure there is only Profile, restart XCode, it should work fine.

Comment: @iphonic: ok i'll let you know